# How do I change Button size from default to sm on mobile using Bootstrap Vue?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-vue

I have a

```
<b-button :size="''" :variant="primary">
```

On the mobile phone, I would like this to be

```
<b-button :size="sm" :variant="primary">
```

In the mounted() callback I tried adding a window.resize listener but I have to hardcode the device width values. Is there any method provided by Bootstrap vue that lets me detect size breakpoints in code. Some help would be appreciated

Comment: *Is there any method provided by Bootstrap vue that lets me detect size breakpoints*? NAFAIK. The window.resize listener would be the way.

Answer (score 2):

You can define the button 2 times. One for mobile and desktop. With the *"d-hidden"* can you hide the element on a viewport/width.

Read here: https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/layout/responsive-utilities/

Alternatively you can use the bootstrap display property for example: "*d-none d-sm-block*".
Nothing is shown if the width is smaller as sm.

Read here: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/utilities/display/

Edit: It works in both (bootstrap/bootstrap-vue) - See here: https://bootstrap-vue.js.org/docs/reference/utility-classes

Comment: This question is related to bootstrap-vue :) the same button's size should be '' on desktop but 'sm' on phone without hardcoding size values in window.onresize

Comment: - Edit post: add reference